# correct way to interpolate two jquery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements and I want to:

- show the first element,
- change its color
- iterate to the next one

I tried to implement this rewriting a function that I have written that just changed the color of each li element but I get to no point and I see no errors that can help me to debug.

The code:

```js
function highlight() {
  // Add highlight class to first li element that isn't highlighted
  $("#risultato li h2:not(.text-danger)").first().show('slow', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).addClass('text-danger')
    }, 1500);
  });

  // Check if any more li exist without the highlight class
  // (This avoids an endless loop)
  // Repeat process
  if ($("#risultato li h2:not(.text-danger)").length != 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      highlight();
    }, 1500);
  } else {
    //do something when the animation has ended
    //not in scope for the question
  }
}



$(function() {
  highlight();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="risultato">
  <li style="display: none">
    <h2>Step1</h2>
  </li>
  <li style="display: none">
    <h2>Step2</h2>
  </li>
  <li style="display: none">
    <h2>Step3</h2>
  </li>
  <li style="display: none">
    <h2>Step4</h2>
  </li>
  <li style="display: none">
    <h2>Step5</h2>
  </li>
  <li style="display: none">
    <h2>Step6</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're targeting and trying to show the `h2` elements, yet it's the `li` which are hidden. You can also simplify the logic slightly to perform the check and queue the next item in a single iteration, like this:

```js
let $ul = $('#risultato');
let showNextLi = () => {
  $ul.find('li:hidden:first').show('slow', function() {
    let $li = $(this);
    if ($li.next().length) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        showNextLi();
        $li.addClass('danger')
      }, 1500);
    } else {
      console.log('complete, do something else here...');
    }
  });
}

showNextLi();
```

```css
#risultato li { 
  display: none; 
  list-style-type: none;
}
#risultato li.danger { 
  color: #C00; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="risultato">
  <li><h2>Step1</h2></li>
  <li><h2>Step2</h2></li>
  <li><h2>Step3</h2></li>
  <li><h2>Step4</h2></li>
  <li><h2>Step5</h2></li>
  <li><h2>Step6</h2></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: actually i want to delay a few seconds between when I show the item and when I change it's color. I have to keep using setTimeout or can I use delay()?

Comment: In that case you can move the `addClass()` in to the `setTimeout()` as well. I've updated the answer to show you how

Comment: correct, I can reuse the first timeout for this. Light and useful. Thank you very much for the lesson! :-)